# Graphs in Java - How to attach a matrix to an edge?

Tags: java, matrix, graph

My graph is represented through an adjacency matrix and I want to build a method which can add a matrix [M x N] to a chosen edge. What is missing or wrong in my code? Note that the graph is acyclic.

```
public class Graph {

 /** Class Graph attributes */

    int [][] grafoo;    

/** Constructor */ 

public Graph (int dim)
{
    grafoo = new int [dim][dim];

    int i=0, j;     
    while(i<dim)
    {
        j=0;
        while(j<dim)
        {
            grafoo[i][j]=0;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}


/** Method add_edge */   //receives two nodes and places to the graph an edge from one node to another with a matrix MxN (for example M=4 and N=5).


void add_edge(int i, int j) // my problem is at this part, representing an edge through a matrix instead of the number 1(usual to say there is a edge in a matrix of adjacency)
{
            int[][] E = new int[M][N];      
            grafoo[i][j]= E;        
}
```

Comment: Has your graph weighted edges?

Comment: Yes it has, the weight is one of the parameters of the matrix that I need to put on the edge.

Comment: You should **definitely** consider an alternative representation for that. I think there should at least be some sort of `Edge` class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Matrix for an edge can't be saved in the 2 dimenrional `grafoo` field (at least not in a sane way). A 2D array of matrices is needed for that, i.e. `int[][][][]` since according to a comment it seems possible to get the weight of the edge from the matrix.

If it isn't possible to get the weight from the matrix, a class that has two fields should be to intoduced:

```
class Edge {
    int[][] matrix;
    int weight;
    // TODO: non-default-costructor(s)? ...
    // TODO: change visibities / add final modifier if appropriate
}
```

The type of `grafoo` should then be changed to `Edge[][]`.

---

**One more thing:** Newly created arrays are initialized with the initial values (see [jls-4.12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)) automatically, i.e. `0` for `int`, `null` for reference types, ...

Therefore the while-loops should be removed or at least put into comments, if that helps understanding, what happens.

`new int[dim][dim][][]` would create a 2D array containing only `null` values (waiting to be filled with `int[][]`s)

Also `Integer.MIN_VALUE` *may* be a better representation for a non-existing edge than `0` (assuming the while loops are there to initialize all edges to be non-existent).

Comment: instead of int [][][][], is it possible to define the grafoo as Object [][]?

Comment: @user8885 of course it is possible, added some code to the answer. However using `Object[][]` would be bad practice, since you would then have to cast the values and therefore pass up the chance to profit from type checking of the compiler and IDEs. If you even thought of putting objects of different types in the array (i.e. `Integer` **and** `int[][]`): That is a bad idea in most cases, since you would then hava to check types + cast every time you use a value.